# Merged cells in Jira

Tags: jira

A table that have merged cells, and some of them are empty cells.
Jira affected the way the table is visually expected to be displayed

I have this kind of tables, I want to merge the cell 'e' and the empty cell

```
||Heading 1||Heading 2||dgg||
|a|b|c|
|d|e| |
|f|f|g|
```

the way the output is displayed is distorted. I want that new cell to contain 'e' and have the same width as the one above/below it.

Comment: How is this question about programming?

Comment: maybe not programming, but helps in the other side of programming.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not implemented.

See https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-44004